# Remove columns from xts objects and merge

Tags: r

I need adjusted closing prices from all S&P500 stocks into one xts object.

```
getSymbols("AAPL;AMZN;...")
```

I know how to do it separately

```
AAPL <- AAPL[,6]
AMZN <- AMZN[,6]
```

but doing this 500 times would be too much.

Finally I would like to merge them Also i would like to merge them. Something like this

```
S&P <- AAPL;AMZN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `environment` for allocating the stocks then you can extract what you want. `Ad`is better if you need the adjusted column.

```
e <- new.env()
stks <- "AAPL;AMZN;IBM;MSFT;GOOG;TSLA"
getSymbols(stks, env = e)

sp=eapply(env = e,Ad)
spf=do.call("merge",sp)
tail(spf)

# > tail(spf)
#                TSLA.Adjusted AAPL.Adjusted IBM.Adjusted GOOG.Adjusted AMZN.Adjusted MSFT.Adjusted
# 2019-05-31        185.16        175.07       126.99       1103.63       1775.07        123.68
# 2019-06-03        178.97        173.30       128.27       1036.23       1692.69        119.84
# 2019-06-04        193.60        179.64       132.69       1053.05       1729.56        123.16
# 2019-06-05        196.59        182.54       131.49       1042.22       1738.50        125.83
# 2019-06-06        205.95        185.22       132.22       1044.34       1754.36        127.82
# 2019-06-07        204.50        190.15       133.31       1066.04       1804.03        131.40
```